# chromecast - android ccl log statements

Tags: android, chromecast

Im new with gradle builds and dont understand why im not getting any of the LOGD statements included in logcat.

In the ccl, in gen/ccl/BuildConfig.java , i show:

public final static boolean DEBUG = true;

AFAIK that should be sufficient to include the ccl's logs in logcat but they are not there.

I used ./gradlew installDebugTests  and installDebug to install the debug apk.

It shows log statements from the sender app but not from the ccl.

Earlier i built with ant and got all the ccl log statements just fine but cant figure out gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is caused by a bug in gradle that doesn't propagate that.. There is no trivial work around for that, and the gradle folks say it is non-trivial to fix it. What I personally do in my local repo is that I add "true ||" to the if-clause of the LOGD block to get that working in my local repo. Here is a reference to the bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52962